# How to add mouse hover functionality in my eclipse application?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse application, written in a language similar to C. I want to add the tooltip information on my auto generated file, for example, I have my generated file :

```
// Comment Header for fast_user_action_rules.csd
//
// Action Rules

    // 'sorting the lsb'
    {
        0x0000, 0x0000, // 32-bit Data
        0x00020000,     // Repli/Fwd Port, Mod Rule
        0x01            // Action
    }

// End of fast_user_action_rules.csd
```

Now when I mouse hover onto the     0x0002000, the tooltip should show the information. Anyone knows how to achieve this?  Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'written in a language similar to C'?  Is the plug-in written in Java, as most others are?  What control type is the text being displayed in?

Comment: It is a .csd file in this case, the only mouse hover feature I want to add on is for the bit 0x00020000, nothing else. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Read [Eclipse FAQ How do I add hover support to my text editor?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_hover_support_to_my_text_editor%3F)

Cheers,
Max

Comment: hmm, Do I have to add the AST support in my eclipse? because the eclipse application is a custom version of eclipse, and it does not have any AST support. Please advise, Thanks!

Comment: You don't need AST for hovers. Implement ITextHover.getHoverRegion to detect range of text to be inspected  and ITextHover..getHoverInfo/ITextHoverExtension2.getHoverInfo2 to return string/object for the region above.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you explained a bit more about how to implement ITextHover? and where should that implementation located in order for the .csd file to recognize ?

Comment: See Eclipse FAQ page above for both answers.

Comment: Thank you!! Now one more question (Sorry if I bother you too much.) Is it possible to add a pop up window when I double click on a group of text such as 0x0000200 , a window will pop up instead of the mouse hovering? This will solve the hover delay too. Thanks!

Comment: See org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration.getDoubleClickStrategy